# Search Specific character in a string

Tags: php, string, php-5.3

I want to get a specific character in a string and than show all string that is next to that character and want to show, can you please help me on this...

**String:**

```
 $teamslist = "BAL@NYY,PIT@CHC,PHI@MIA,BAL@NYY,TOR@TB,DET@CLE,NYM@WSH,TEX@ATL,KC@BOS,MIL@CIN,CWS@MIN,STL@COL,ARI@SD,LAA@HOU,SEA@OAK,SF@LAD
";
```

**Character That need to find is:**

```
 $tag = 'PIT';
```

**Result that i want to need is:**

```
  @CHC,PHI@MIA,BAL@NYY,TOR@TB,DET@CLE,NYM@WSH,TEX@ATL,KC@BOS,MIL@CIN,CWS@MIN,STL@COL,ARI@SD,LAA@HOU,SEA@OAK,SF@LAD
```

Please provide some code that could help me to find my desired result..

Comment: Aren't you going to try and solve it yourself first? Might be a good idea

Comment: Please provide the attempt to achieve the desired result

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where you ask people to do your work for you, you must show an attempt to reach a desired goal beforehand. See the [posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: strrchr($teamslist,$tag)."<br>";
i tried this code but it's providing me this result..."PHI@MIA,BAL@NYY,TOR@TB,DET@CLE,NYM@WSH,TEX@ATL,KC@BOS,MIL@CIN,CWS@MIN,STL@COL,ARI@SD,LAA@HOU,SEA@OAK,SF@LAD" while i need this one as well from start "@CHC,"

Comment: @SamHolmes i still did'nt get it why people start giving advise instead of helping here.. this is place where people come for help ...so please help others...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr()` in this case:

```
$teamslist = "BAL@NYY,PIT@CHC,PHI@MIA,BAL@NYY,TOR@TB,DET@CLE,NYM@WSH,TEX@ATL,KC@BOS,MIL@CIN,CWS@MIN,STL@COL,ARI@SD,LAA@HOU,SEA@OAK,SF@LAD";
$tag = 'PIT';
$teamslist = substr($teamslist, strpos($teamslist, $tag)+strlen($tag));
echo $teamslist;
```

Comment: There is an edge case of 2 characters before the `@` and 3 after.

Comment: @Flosculus what do you mean edge case? could you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = '';
$teamslist = "BAL@NYY,PIT@CHC,PHI@MIA,BAL@NYY,TOR@TB,DET@CLE,NYM@WSH,TEX@ATL,KC@BOS,MIL@CIN,CWS@MIN,STL@COL,ARI@SD,LAA@HOU,SEA@OAK,SF@LAD";   
$pos = strpos($teamslist,'PIT') + 3; //+3 is to count PIT position as well

if($pos !== FALSE){
     $result = substr($teamslist, $pos, strlen($teamlist));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply use `explode()`, because you have a delimiter, which is the `$tag`. `$result[0]` would contain everything BEFORE the `$tag` in the `$teamslist`, and `$result[1]` would contain everything AFTER. The parameter "2" just tells the explode function to only retrieve 2 pieces. So even there are more occurrences of the `$tag` in the `$teamslist` string, it would still split on the first one found.

```
$teamslist = "BAL@NYY,PIT@CHC,PHI@MIA,BAL@NYY,TOR@TB,DET@CLE,NYM@WSH,TEX@ATL,KC@BOS,MIL@CIN,CWS@MIN,STL@COL,ARI@SD,LAA@HOU,SEA@OAK,SF@LAD
";
$tag = "PIT";
$result = explode($tag, $teamslist, 2);
echo $result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you using strpos to get position of "PIT", after using substr

Or

using preg_match('\PIT(*+)\', $teamslist, $matchs);